# Singularities and their Residues

Tags: complex-analysis

i have the function $$f(z)= \frac{\sin(z)}{(z-1)(\sinh(z))}$$
and i need to find the residue for the singularities.

I have found the two singularities to be $z=1$, and $z=0$

I found the residue for $z=1$ as $\frac{\sin(1)}{\sinh(1)}$

I wanted to clarify if $z=0$ is an actual singularity, and if so how would i find the residue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations for the singularity at $z=1$ seem correct to me. The singularity at $z=0$ is removable because $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0} z f(z)=0.$and therefore has residue $0$.

Comment: i'm just wondering with regards to removable singularities, is a singularity called removable if the $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0} z f(z)=0 $??

Answer (score 0):

since
$$
\sin x = x + ... \\
\sinh x = x + ...
$$

the function has a *removable* 'singularity' and can be treated by *defining* a function $g(x)$ which is $\frac{\sin(z)}{(z-1)(\sinh(z))}$ if $z \ne 0$, and takes the value $-1$ at $x=0$.

this function has no singularity, and no residue need be computed

Comment: so you're saying this function has no singularities? not even at $z=1$?

Comment: $g(x)$  has a genuine singularity at $z=1$. a pole with the residue mentioned by OP. it is called a meromorphic function

Comment: the phantom downvoter is active tonight ;-). to me they are creatures of the shadows who dare not speak their names, not lovers of study and knowledge.

Comment: @DavidHolden I downvoted because you said that the function has no singularities, while there is actually 1 essential singularity.

Comment: @VladimirLenin I believe that David Holden meant that there is no singularity at $z=0$.  Perhaps you should neutralize the down vote.  +1

Comment: i've no objection to downvotes per se, but they are not much help unless accompanied by an explanation. what i call anonymous or phantom downvotes are merely discouraging. this occurs due to what i perceicve as a minor weakness in the stack exchange modus operandi, but (imao) we should work around that rather than use it as an excuse for what may sometimes be slightly curmudgeonly behaviour. thx @Dr.MV for your decent attitude ;-)

Comment: @DavidHolden I do have objection when the down vote is for an illegitimate reason.  Case and point.  A user gave a down vote because he/she claimed that $\int e^{at}dt=\frac1a e^{at}$ was invalid if $a$ were not real.  Even after I showed that it is valid for complex $a$, the user became offensive.

Comment: @Dr.MV i know what you mean. i've also had downvotes to good answers. i don't see any real justification for downvotes, except perhaps for the odd posts that are off topic or plain silly. what's wrong with simply pointing out a mistake? as a self-taught person i value having my misapprehensions corrected, and my errors pointed out. since i love mathematics, my aim is to gradually develop mathematical maturity. i have no math "peer group" or teachers except MSE, and neither money, career, nor kudos has any place in my scheme of things.